# Access object in JavaScript array by id or unique prop with O(1)

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an array of objects like this:

```
const myArray = [
  { id: 'a', label: 'A' },
  { id: 'b', label: 'B' },
  ...
];
```

Is there a way to access any object in this array by id with constant O(1) time complexity?

Comment: By not using an array. Just use a `Map` instead!

Comment: Just beware that if you use a reference table of some kind you might need to take care of memory leaks. It would be better, I think, to create the initial array with Map, as Bergi mentions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a hash table with an object without prototypes.

This works without using a library.

```js
var array = [{ id: 'a', label: 'A' }, { id: 'b', label: 'B' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);
    
array.forEach(o => hash[o.id] = o);

console.log(hash['a']);
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which works with any type of the used key, without converting it to a string.

```js
var array = [{ id: 'a', label: 'A' }, { id: 'b', label: 'B' }],
    map = new Map(array.map(o => [o.id, o]));
    
console.log(map.get('a'));
```

Comment: Using `Map` API is neat.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const myArray = [
  { id: 'a', label: 'A' },
  { id: 'b', label: 'B' }
];

let value = "b";

let found = myArray.find(({id}) => id === value);

console.log(found);
```

Comment: To meet the O(1) time complexity requirement of the question, that would depend on the imlementation of `find` implementing some optimisations I wouldn't expect (and which don't appear in [MDN's pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)). Do you know of any implementations of `find` that have those optimisations?

Comment: @Quentin You got lot of spelling mistakes. Fix them first please.

Comment: @Quentin `find` is *required* by the spec (and reality) to call the callback on every array element, it cannot be optimised. (Otherwise you'd have to prove that the callback is a pure function, figure out what it does, know something about the array that we don't, and use a shortcut)

Comment: @Quentin Not sure what you mean. Once a match is found the callback is no longer called. _"The find method executes the callback function once for each index of the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that element."_ Do shed illumination here upon the topic as to how `.find()` does not meet requirement.

Comment: @Quentin Do you intend to share your knowledge relevant to the topic in a more in depth manner? Or is simply stating the code does not meet requirement suffice for the purpose of enlightening another as to what they are missing and how to improve the Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 — "Once a match is found the callback is no longer called" — That's the point. If the element being looked for is the first one then it takes less time to find than if it were the last one. That's linear time (O(n)) complexity, not constant time (O(1)) complexity.